# Performing regression in terms of X'X and X'Y

Tags: regression, least-squares, large-data

I've heard that some people like to operate directly on X'X and X'Y rather than X and Y. I think this may be in the context of big data, to save space, but I am not sure. What is the point of such approach, what does it achieve? Is this a standard trick I am not aware of?

Comment: Because $\hat\beta=(X'X)^{-1}X'y$?

Comment: Most software "operates directly" on these matrices to perform ordinary least square fitting.

Comment: Who, exactly, is saying what, exactly? It's hard to discuss a statement we can't actually see the context of, which leaves us guessing what their argument might be.

Comment: Do not vandalize your question. Now that it has an upvoted answer, it cannot be deleted. The question needs to stand so that the answer will have sufficient context to be understandable.

Answer (score 4):

(Taking my best guess as to the point being made)

Aside from doing very large problems (n and p huge), most standard regression programs use QR decomposition, though some use SVD or Cholesky decomposition.

QR decomposition finds $X=QR$ where $Q$ is orthogonal and $R$ upper triangular, so $X^\top X b = X^\top y$ becomes $R^\top R b = R^\top Q^\top y$, which reduces to solving $R b = Q^\top y$.

Consider that if $n$ is say $2\times 10^8$ and $p$ is say $5$, $X$ has a billion elements but $X^\top X$ has $25$ and $X^\top y$ has $5$.

So when it comes to solving $(X^\top X)b = X^\top y$ is seems like it's a lot easier to compute $X'X$ and $X'y$ and solve for $b$ (perhaps via Cholesky decomposition).

However, to a extent that's partly illusory. While it is slower to use QR decomposition (and SVD) than Cholesky decomposition, a lot of the overhead tends to come because the usual implementations make a full copy of X before operating on it in pace to produce R. This is not strictly necessary (though it may involve considerable effort to avoid in some situations), and if I recall correctly a carefully implemented QR designed for a tall, skinny $X$ that doesn't try to take a copy of X (pass by ref, and only allocate/use the space it actually needs) should only take about twice as long as a standard Cholesky.

(e.g. see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.1071.pdf )

While Cholesky can be faster (and if the QR is not very carefully implemented, maybe quite a bit faster), it is not as stable. On particular kinds of problems it can be quite handy, though.

The Cholesky can also be made more stable, at a similar cost to that for a QR specifically designed for a tall, skinny matrix.

So in part it depends on which QR algorithm, and which Cholesky algorithm and what shape of problem you have and how much you care about stability.

[As someone once said, if you don't mind about the accuracy of the answer, you can have it as fast as you like.]